# Forked package fails to build

Tags: npm, package, agm

I have forked a package `@agm/markerclusterer`, here: https://github.com/neverlose-lv/angular-google-maps

I have made a commit.

And now I want to use my "patched" version, instead of original one.

But my build fails, because other modules, that are required by this package, are not loaded.
Pay attention, that the markerclusterer is not a single dependency of the repo.
May be that is the problem? How to deal with that?

How can I fix this problem?
Am I correctly injecting my fork in the package.json?

I replaced `"@agm/markerclusterer": "^3.0.0-beta.0",` with `"@agm/markerclusterer": "git+ssh://git@github.com/neverlose-lv/angular-google-maps.git#eed277876549b58b41ee7d9515a47f07e5cb3115",`

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyProjectName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "build-sandbox": "ng build -c sandbox",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "updates": "ncu -x '/^(@types/googlemaps|typescript)$/'"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "^1.1.0",
    "@agm/markerclusterer": "git+ssh://git@github.com/neverlose-lv/angular-google-maps.git#eed277876549b58b41ee7d9515a47f07e5cb3115",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "3.3.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.3.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "3.3.2",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.7",
    "@google/markerclustererplus": "^5.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.9.1",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.18.1",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.0.2",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",
    "@ngxs-labs/actions-executing": "^0.1.9",
    "@ngxs-labs/dispatch-decorator": "^3.1.0",
    "@ngxs-labs/emitter": "^3.0.1",
    "@ngxs-labs/immer-adapter": "^3.0.5",
    "@ngxs-labs/select-snapshot": "^3.0.0",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngxs/router-plugin": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.3",
    "@sumsub/websdk": "^1.3.0",
    "agm-direction": "0.8.9",
    "agm-spiderfier": "^1.0.5",
    "angular-datetimerangepicker": "^2.4.4",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.1",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.2",
    "crypto-pro": "^2.3.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.25",
    "flag-icon-css": "^4.1.6",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.25",
    "immer": "^9.0.7",
    "ion-intl-tel-input": "^1.0.5",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.9.0",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-doc-viewer": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-dropzone": "^3.0.0",
    "ngxs-reset-plugin": "^1.4.1",
    "nl2br-pipe": "^1.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "ts-overlapping-marker-spiderfier": "^1.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "url-polyfill": "^1.1.12",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.0.3",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.3.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.3",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.11",
    "capacitor-resources": "^2.0.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: I have investigated some things.

Comment: When I use my package - it loads. I see the source code. So I use it correctly on package.json, but... it is installed as you can see it here - the full source of the repository. But when it is installed as original package - then there is a build files, instead of the source.